Router does not work after NextAuth Middleware Redirect
I've got NextAuth (mostly) working.  The only case where I have issues is when I get redirected to the login page (with a callback in the url parameters) by the middleware.  Then, no matter what I do, the app router will not push/replace/refresh the page.  I know it's getting to that block of code, but it just does not do anything.
My login function:
  const [serverError, setServerError] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isSubmitting },
    reset,
    setError,
  } = useForm<TSignUpSchema>({
    resolver: zodResolver(signUpSchema),
  });
  
  const onSubmit = async (data: TSignUpSchema) => {
    let { id, password } = data;
    if(id.toLowerCase().startsWith('u')){
      id = id.substring(1);
    }
    const res = await signIn("credentials", {
      id,
      password,
      redirect: false,
    });
    if (res?.error) {
      reset();
      if (res?.status === 401) {
        setServerError("Invalid credentials.  Please try again");
      }
      if (res?.status === 418) {
        setServerError(
          "Something went wrong.\nIf this problem continues, contact support."
        );
      }
    }
    if (res && res.ok) {

      router.replace('/map'); **//THIS DOES NOT WORK AFTER MIDDLEWARE REDIRECT**
   
    }
  };

Middleware.ts
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";

export default withAuth({

  pages: {
    signIn: '/login', // Redirect to this page if not authenticated
  },
});

export const config = {
  matcher:  ['/map'], // Protect all routes under (protected)
};

app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts
const authOptions = {
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt', // Use JSON Web Tokens for session handling
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 30, // Session will last 30 days
    updateAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 10, // Extend session duration by 10 days on each use
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
        token.email = user.email;
        token.name = user.name;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user.id = token.id;
      session.user.email = token.email;
      session.user.name = token.name;
      return session;
    }
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: 'credentials',
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        id: { label: "ID", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
      },
      authorize: async (credentials) => {
        const result = signUpSchema.safeParse(credentials);
        if (result.error) return null;

        try {
            //check username/password and return user if valid

       
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
          return null;
        }
      }
    })
  ]
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

I'm expecting router to replace current page with '/map' after succesfull login.....instead it just sits there.
